# Why doesn't the delete operator change the length of an array?

Tags: javascript

As an example, when using the `delete` operator on an index of an Array, the index is removed, such as any property of any object would be.

This is proven by:

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

delete arr[1];

if(1 in arr)
    alert("It didn't work!");
```

If you were to run this block, you will find that the text "It didn't work!" will never be alerted to the user. This is because the property belonging as index `1` on the Array has been deleted.

Now, here is where things get weird...

Although an index is deleted from an Array, the Array length shall remain the same:

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

alert(arr.length); //will alert '3'

delete arr[2];

alert(arr.length); //will still alert '3'
```

When looking at the Array `arr` in the debugger (in Chrome at least), you will see that the index `2` does not even exist, **so why does the length still report as 3?**

[Here is a JSFiddle to play around with.](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/8140uj75/)

Comment: I did not see these posts before-hand, as they did not appear during my searches. I agree that my question may be a duplicate. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the array actually loses the key when you call delete one of it's keys, so if you do

```
Object.keys(arr)
```

you would see that the key is missing and replaced by undefined.

edit:
the other posts mentioned have better answers, but here is my take.
delete doesn't adjust the size , when you all push, put gets called using the last size it knows. some browsers just show undefined instead of the deleted value key.

Comment: Woah! That's actually really cool! Thanks @Abraham Adam!